# Google Sheets / Формат ячеек значения которых совпадают с значениями из массива

Tags: node.js, google-spreadsheet

Подскажите, как менять визуальное содержание в ячейке (фон, цвет шрифта), при условии что значение которое храниться в данной ячейке совпадает со значением проверяемого массива. (Если хоть одно совпадает, менять) [ConditionalFormatRule](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#ConditionalFormatRule)
[image: Google sheet]

Вот код который мне помог составить [@Spatz](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195483/spatz) Но к сожалению он не отрабатывает как надо. И вылетает с ошибкой. А знаний и примеров не хватает.

```
const client = new google.auth.JWT(
    keys.client_email,
    null,
    keys.private_key,
    ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
)

const gsapi = google.sheets({
    version: 'v4',
    auth: client
})

const spreadsheetIdCurr = '1pircQiSbWuiaMVOVFi9ZfVizB5KEx4YSh7FqdWEp4_f';

const checkData = {values: ["aaa", "b"]};

async function colorizeResult() {

    res = await gsapi.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
        spreadsheetId: spreadsheetIdCurr,
        requestBody: {
            requests: [
                {
                    updateCells: {
                        range: {
                            sheetId: 0,
                            startColumnIndex: 0,
                            endColumnIndex: 5,
                            startRowIndex: 0,
                            endRowIndex: 2,
                        },
                    },
                    addConditionalFormatRule: {
                        rule: {
                            booleanRule: {
                                condition: {
                                    type: "ONE_OF_LIST",
                                    values: [{userEnteredFormat: {userEnteredValue: checkData[0]}},
                                        {userEnteredFormat: {userEnteredValue: checkData[1]}},],
                                },
                                format: {
                                    textFormat: {
                                        bold: true,
                                        foregroundColor: {red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1}
                                    },
                                    backgroundColor: {red: 0.1, green: 0.3, blue: 1}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            ]
        },
    })

}
colorizeResult();
```

Comment: Обязательно скриптом? Можно с помощью **Условного форматирования**

Comment: Если надо отсеивать динамически загружаемые значения в ячейках по массиву из >100 значений, то - да. Это надо делать скриптом

Comment: А какая ошибка? Может быть в авторизации проблема?

Comment: ```(node:10700) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid value at 'requests[0]' (oneof), oneof field 'kind' is already set. Cannot set 'addConditionalFormatRule' ```